# How can I count how many times a sum of substrings is contained in a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, python-requests

this is the string and the subtotal:
`int_seq='3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'`

```
subtotal = 9
```

so the function must return 7 and this is why:

```html
3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'
__'0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0'_____________
__'0,4,0,3,1,0,1'_______________
____'4,0,3,1,0,1,0'_____________
____'4,0,3,1,0,1'_______________
____________________'0,0,5,0,4'_
______________________'0,5,0,4'_
________________________'5,0,4'_
```

Most likely what I really don't understand is how to use a for, furthemore, I cannot use external libraries.

Comment: What have you try so far?

Comment: Your explanation isn't clear

Comment: What is a subtotal? I am not sure what calculation you are trying to accomplish

Answer (score 1):

You could track a starting point (index) and a cumulative sum from that starting point. Each time your cumulative sum reaches or surpasses the target, you move the starting point forward, subtracting the old value, until the sum goes back below the target.  During this process, each time the cumulative sum is equal to the target, you have an eligible substring that you can count.

However this won't work perfectly unless we take into account the effect of zeroes.  For example, when we get to [0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1], the last 1 makes the sum greater than 9 so we move the start position to get [4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1] but that is still greater than 9 because we're already passed the penultimate zero so two valid subranges would be skipped. [4,0,3,1,0,1,0] and [4,0,3,1,0,1].  To work around this while retaining linear performance, we need to perform the range shrinking before adding the last item to the sum and count one extra subrange for each trailing zero when the sum matches the target.

```
S = '3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'
target = 9

N = list(map(int,S.split(',')))

start  = 0
cumSum = 0
count  = 0
for end,value in enumerate(N+[target+1]): # force out ending subranges
    while cumSum+value>target and start<end:
        cumSum -= N[start]    # shrink range
        start  += 1
        if cumSum==target:    # count matches (+extra for trailing zeroes)
            count += next((c for c,v in enumerate(N[end-1:start:-1],1) if v),1)
    cumSum += value           # extend range
    count  += cumSum==target  # count matches
    
print(count) # 7
```

If you want to know exactly which substrings produce the target sum, you can change the loop slightly to print them out and get proof that it works:

```
S = '3,0,4,0,3,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,5,0,4,2'
target = 9

N = list(map(int,S.split(',')))

start  = 0
cumSum = 0
count  = 0
for end,value in enumerate(N+[target+1]): # force out ending subranges
    while cumSum+value>target and start<end:
        cumSum -= N[start]    # shrink range
        start  += 1
        if cumSum==target:    # count matches (+extra for trailing zeroes)
            c = next((c for c,v in enumerate(N[end-1:start:-1],1) if v),1)
            print([start,end],N[start:end],f"Matches {c}")
    cumSum += value           # extend range
    if cumSum==target:
        print([start,end+1],N[start:end+1],"Matches 1")

[1, 8] [0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1] Matches 1
[1, 9] [0, 4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0] Matches 1
[2, 9] [4, 0, 3, 1, 0, 1, 0] Matches 2
[10, 15] [0, 0, 5, 0, 4] Matches 1
[11, 15] [0, 5, 0, 4] Matches 1
[12, 15] [5, 0, 4] Matches 1
```